# use different messages for input email fields: jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 different pages login and sign up with email fields of similar nature like shown below. I'm using jquery validate plugin to do field validation. I need to show two different error messages for the email fields depending on the page it is placed in. Is it possible to do that by writing some custom validation using "addMethod" function or by any other method? Do I add a class to distinguish both the email fields to achieve that? Any pointers

```
<form id="login">
    <input type="email" class="required"/>
</form>

<form id="signup">
    <input type="email" class="required"/>
</form>

    rules: {
                            username: {
                                required: true,
                                email: true
                            },
                            password: {
                                 required: true
                            }

                        },
                        messages: {
                            username: {
                                required: "please enter an email address",
                                email: "You must use a valid email address."
                            },
                            password:{
                                required: "",
                                password: "You must use a valid password."
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: If these are different pages, just put different messages in the options to `.validate()`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: all the pages use the common validate file and the id of the forms are passed to the validate function depending on the page it is showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function the messages parameter:

```
messages: {
  username: {
    required: "please enter an email address",
    email: function() {
      if ($("#login")) { return "Message for login page"; }
      else if ($("#signup")) { return "Message for signup page"; }
      else { return "Generic message" }
  },
  password: ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, there's no way for these functions to know which form is being processed by `.validate()`, but they can look at the contents of the page. So this just checks whether the page has a `login` or `signup` ID.